# The volume of a solid of revolution about $x$-axis, bounded by $f(x)=\frac {x} {1+x^3}$ and the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus

I am trying to compute the volume of the region bounded by the $x$-axis and the function: $$f(x)= \frac {x} {1+x^3} $$

My solution:  $$\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x^2} {(1+x^3)^2} dx = \frac {\pi} {3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1} {(1+x^3)^2} d(1+x^3) = \frac {\pi} {3} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {u^2} du = -\frac {\pi} {3} \frac {1}{u}|_1^{\infty}=-\frac {\pi} {3} \cdot (-\frac{1} {2}) = \frac {\pi} {6}$$

after passing the limit. This is multiple-choice question of which the answer is $\frac {\pi} {3}$. Any comments on correction?

Should I also consider the interval $(-\infty, -1)$ and $(-1, 0)$ in the domain of the function?

Comment: You had everything right until the last step. $1/1 = 1$, not $1/2$

Comment: I see! I was plugging in the $1$ into $1+x^3$ instead of $u$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote $ -\frac {\pi} {3} \frac {1}{u}|_1^{\infty}=-\frac {\pi} {3} \cdot (-\frac{1} {2})$. The factor $ - \frac{1}{2}$ is wrong. The correct factor is $-1$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Everything ok. Pay attention to the limits of integration $(1,\infty)$ ok. But after $u$ substitution need not go back to lower limit $0$, and and no need of negative $(-1,-\infty)$ limits once again.